# fire an event after document is rendered

Tags: jquery

How to fire an event or call a method after the document body is fully rendered in jQuery

Comment: what about $(document).ready ?

Comment: doesnt help. It gets fired before onLoad of body

Comment: Because `load` fires after all the images are loaded. Normally waiting for images is undesirable as this can take some time. What is it that you really want to do? If you describe your problem better, you will get better answers.

Comment: I have a page(Page1) on which one table is getting generated dynamically. When I render this page's html on other page(prinpage.aspx) for printing using window.open(), i want to disable all the controls on that print page. As the table is getting rendered dynamically on PAge1, PrintPage's document.ready is not able to locate the controls inside that table. Hence those controls are not getting disabled. Hence I was looking for a method or an event that can be called after whole body is rendered. Please Let me know if there is anyother way to do this.using Jquery

Comment: Ah, that makes a huge difference. Please have a look at my answers, although some random person has downvoted it with no reason.

Comment: Is this problem happening because rendering takes "some time" and the page layout may change dramatically due to this. I've got a similar problem: I change the innerHtml of a DIV, then I want to scroll the window to the bottom of that div. However, if the changes are complex, it'll scroll to what ends up being mid-way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to your clarification in the comment:

It depends on how you generate the table (more information would be good). But in general, no, there is no event for that. You have to call the function when you finished building the table.

```
buildTable();
hideControls();
```

If you use Ajax for building the table, then you have to hide the controls inside the callback for the Ajax request.

**Update:**

You could also consider to use a different CSS stylesheet for that page which hides the control elements.

Comment: If there is no explanation why you down voted, I cannot improve my answer. Thank you :) If you don't comment I will just assume that you have no clue about the issue at hand.

Comment: good guess. There was an ajax call which was pulling data from the service and generating the table. Commented the ajax call if the page is print page and it started working.Thanks

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the Ajax callback can be used to hide the controls

Answer (score 2):

Try binding an event on load in your ready function:

```
$(function(){
   $(window).load(function(){
      // Do stuff after everything has been loaded
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of JQuery events to do this (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). What worked for me was to create 2x handlers for the "ready" event. The first initializes the doc and loads the contents (using KnockoutJS bindings). The second fires jscript code to render canvas controls that were created by the first.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//document fully loaded
$('#subbtn').click();  // fire the click event on a form button
});
```

Comment: This is basically the same as my answer. If you think it is not  and that your code has some important difference, then you should state that explicitly because I cannot see it.

Comment: Its a more complete code sample, but yes it uses the same elements as your answer.

Comment: $(document).ready fires after DOM load, it does NOT wait until contents are actually rendered, so it doesn't help if you want to fire an event the moment the page is "fully rendered" (as asked).