# $(window).on("load") not triggered in postRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-load, rendr

I have a jquery code that I have to trigger after the page is loaded, I am doing it in postRender function call of the view, but postRender and window load event are totally async, so, the window load event might happen before I am in postRender adding the listener for the load event, is there any replacement for the function in this case, or am I missing something?

thanks for the help

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762959/fire-an-event-after-document-is-rendered

Comment: no actually, rendrJs works on a different way, that's the main issue here

Comment: Sorry missed the rendrJs tag

Comment: can't you insert a script tag in your template with `$(loadFunction)`?

Comment: the $(window).load event is happening before I can ask for it, this is my main problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to keep track of the `window.load` event in the global scope and choose an execution path in `postRender()` based on the status of the flag.

```
// define this in the global scope
var windowHasLoaded = false;
$(window).on('load', function(){
    windowHasLoaded = true;
});
```

Then in `view.postRender()`:

```
// window has already loaded, just run now
if(windowHasLoaded) {
    doStuff();
}
// run on window load event
else {
    $(window).on('load', doStuff);
}

var doStuff = function() {
    // the stuff to do
}
```